# can i recast a differential equation as an array equation to use in matlab?

Tags: matlab, simulation, modeling, differential-equations

I was asked to write a code (.m file) to model a system described by these two equations using matlab

```
y1" = 5 y1' + 6 y1 - 3
y2" = 5 y2' + 4 y1' + 6 y2 - 4
```

These two equations are the only things given
should i write them as an array first and how?

Comment: Check `ode45` and any related tutorial. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html, the very second example, should be sufficient. Just use some other variable name, eg `y11=y1'` and `y21 = y2'`, not that you write those names down just to avoid any mixup. You will end up with 4 equations.

Comment: be careful that `'` means (complex) transposition in MATLAB and not *derivative*. Those are ODEs, so either use the Symbolic Math Toolbox to find an analytic solution or have a look at the numeric solvers

Comment: ok so it should be like this?
t=y1'
t'=5 t + 6 y1 -3
t1 = y2'
t1'=5 t1+4 t+6 y2 -4